# The use of Listening for preference changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, android-settings

After reading the Android documentation about settings , i have a few questions about Listening for preference changes

> "There are several reasons you might want to be notified as soon as the use changes one of the preferences. In order to receive a callback when a change happens to any one of the preferences, implement the SharedPreference.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener interface and register the listener for the SharedPreferences object by calling registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()."

I don't really get it , and I couldn't find why it is important to implement this listener, what is the use of it? what does it do? when to use it? right now , without implementing the listener my settings works fine, is it crucial for any settings or just on a particular cases?
thanks.

resource : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment

Comment: let´s say You will change the description of a preference inside Your PreferenceActivity/Fragment as soon as the user changes anything. Then You can use it...

Comment: If you don't need it, don't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't required to implement an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. It's a capability that's there for convenience.

Sometimes you want to react immediately to a change in preferences. For instance, if you have a "Settings" action where the user can, say, change the background color of an activity, then when the user makes the selection, you'd like the background color to change immediately, not when the user restarts the activity. One way to do this is for the activity to check the status of the background preference in `onResume()`, but another way is for the activity to register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in `onStart` and (unregister it in `onStop`). I've found that using a listener in this way can sometimes lead to simpler code. It also helps greatly when the code that should react to a settings change does not normally participate in the framework's lifecycle methods.

Implementing an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` is pretty straightforward. You just need either declare your class to `implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` or implement an object that does. For instance:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    . . .
    private final OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mPrefsListener =
        new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                                                  String key)
            {
                if (key.equals(IMPORTANT_PREF_KEY)) {
                    setImportantValue(sharedPrefs.getInt(IMPORTANT_PREF_KEY, -1));
                }
            }
        };

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPrefsListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPrefsListener);
    }

    void setImportantValue(int value) {
         . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh i see thank you , and how can I do it? the developer's resources are really bad at explaining this, which activity has to implement the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener? the settings activity that holds my fragment? my fragment? or the activity which will be effected by the change?

Comment: @james - I added some sample code. You can use an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in any code that has access to a `SharedPreferences` object. It doesn't have to be an activity or fragment (although those are commonly where one is used).

Comment: Can you please explain the line setImportantValue(sharedPrefs.getInt(IMPORTANT_PREF_KEY, -1))?

Comment: @james - well, `setImportantValue()` is some fictitious method I invented that presumably does something useful with the current preference setting for `IMPORTANT_PREF_KEY` -- another made-up `String` value for some preference. The method `getInt(String key, int defaultValue)` is part of the `SharedPreferences` API; it retrieves the value of the preference named `key` as an `int`, returning `defaultValue` if the key was not found.

Comment: Ok thanks , for some reason the onSharedPreferenceChanged doesn't get called at all . do you have any idea why? (I have a ViewPager which contains fragments(which implements the listener) and the setting that i changed takes care of something inside the fragment but somehow when i try to change the setting from the ViewPager's activity it doesn't react to any change , the change take care only when restarting the activity)

Comment: @james - Are you sure that you're registering the listener? Are you sure that you are registering it on the same preference object that's being modified?

Comment: yes , i tried to debugg it and  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPrefsListener); indeed gets called when going to the settings and when returning to the activity

Comment: *and unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener respectively

Comment: @james - and are you sure that some shared preference is being set while the listener is registered?

Comment: do you mean inside the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener? i did set it but this method never seems to get invoked

Comment: I have to mention that the only class that implements the listener is the Fragment that gets affected by the preference change and not any class that is related to the PreferenceFragment I don't know if it is related.

Comment: @james - I mean that the mechanism won't work unless a listener is registered at the time that a change in the preferences takes place. It may be that you are unregistering the listener when the `PreferenceFragment` is displayed. Try moving the calls to `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` and `unregister...` to the fragment's `onCreate` and `onDestroy` methods, respectively.

Comment: OK i think I'm starting to get this , my checkbox pref has to change to background of the fragment (which happens in onCreateView) and when I return from the settings the fragment doesn't call this method, and that's why the background doesn't change.. so correct me if I'm wrong but I don't have to implement the listener at all? just to make sure the onCreateView gets notifed to the changes of the boolean? (p.s thank you very much for the time I really appreciate this. I have marked your answer as the right[you do answer my initial question])

Comment: @james - Your analysis sounds correct. It's not all that often that one needs to implement an `OnSharedPreferencesChangeListener`.

Comment: @Ted Hopp I think you are good at preference listeners.
I have similar issue I have posted question ,follow like you said move to onCreate and onDestroy methods of fragment, but no changes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701787/could-not-listen-to-preference-changes
any help I appreciate.